# What's the negative moment of a generalized Chi-squared random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables, chi-squared

Suppose that $X$ is a generalized chi-squared distributed random variable with degree of freedom $k>1$.

I am wondering $${\rm E}\big[X^{-1/2}\big]\ =\ ???$$

How to prove it?

Thank you.

Comment: The first version had a [chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) $\chi^2(k)$, with the follow-up questions of [noncentral chi-squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution) $\chi^2(k,\lambda)$ and [generalized chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution) $\tilde\chi^2(\mathbf w,\mathbf k,\boldsymbol \lambda, m,s)$. For generalized we talk about degrees (plural) of freedom. $\chi^2(k)$ is easy, generalized seems way harder. Do you confirm that the easy case is already solved?

Comment: @Sassatelli Giulio
I have already solved the case when $X$ is $\chi^2(k)$, but I have no idea how to solve it when $X$ is a generalized chi-squared r.v.